# How to fix Firefox unresponsive script warning on server side?

Tags: javascript, java, firefox, caching, gwt

**Situation:**

I have a website that is written in Java (1500 LOC) and compiled to javascript with GWT (Google Web Tools). I started observing "Warning: Unresponsive script" on my website few weeks ago. I got this pop up warning 22 times out of 25 tries.

I can fix this by clearing Firefox browser cache. And after that I saw warning message 1 time / 25 tries.

I am trying to figure out what's the root cause of this. It seems to be a client side issue. My customers are probably not seeing this since they don't load that website as often as I do. However, I feel like they might run into this issue in this future. I wonder if there are something I can do on the server side to eliminate/reduce the occurrence of unresponsive script warning.

**Questions:**

1. I compared Firefox "about:cache" before and after I load my website. The only difference is that a 43 byte cache gets created in memory every time I load the website. Is this something normal?
2. I thought cache is to help users load websites faster, what could be happening in my case? (I guess my website generates new cache every time on load and old cache are not used?)
3. Since clearing the cache can fix this issue, how can I automatically clear cache when user closes my website?
4. Could there be an issue in GWT compiled javascript? Could network speed also be a factor?
5. What else do I need to check and what are the potential solutions to resolve this issue?

Comment: You're going to have to do some profiling to figure out where exactly your application is hanging. Is it in a particular request? What function is taking the most time?

Comment: @KevinWorkman When I see the unresponsive script warning and click on debug script in firefox, it shows me the last line (line 12346) of XXX.cache.html. There is nothing in that line but I am guessing initializing UI fields is taking most of the time. I also observed that this only happens in Firefox but not Chrome. I am not sure if GWT generates different javascripts for different browsers or the two browsers handle javascript differently

Answer (score 0):

1. Install FireBug to Firefox and see what scripts are timing out. Given this is GWT, there is a good chance something is getting stuck on the server side. If so:
2. Run you server under a profiler and see where are the host spots or bottlenecks. I prefer JProfiler, been using it for 10+ years.

Comment: I don't believe this can happen by something doing heavy lifting on the server side.

Can you be a little more specific what is happening on the page where this happens ? Are a lot of UI elements are updated ? A big flextable created ? Lots of calculations ?

Comment: I doubt that the server is the problem. Even if the work on the server takes some time, the connection is still asynchronous and should not block the client. It's more likely that you overtax the browser with your Java code (or rather the Javascript, which is the result of the compiling).

Comment: @Knarf I have more than 100 UI elements to load on this website. Most of the UI elements have some onClick event. And when I see the warning and debug the script in Firefox, it shows me the last line of XXX.cache.html and there is nothing in that line (it's the last line of the file).

Comment: @Akkusativobjekt It kinda weird that this unresponsive script warning only appears in Firefox but not in Chrome. I am not sure if both browsers load javascipt differently or they got different javascript after GWT compile

Comment: @Slava Imeshev Can you clarify how to use FireFox to debug this? I can see something in Firefox debug panel when warning shows up but at that time there is nothing in Firebug console

Comment: Can you give some extra info about those UI widgets ?

Are these added in a loop ?
Do these contain panels, or flextable that are filled in a loop ?